# How to set up night light mode on one monitor and the second one normal

Tags: display, 19.10, settings, night-light

Just like in the title, how can I set up night light mode on one monitor only? Is it even possible to do such a thing?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with basic flavor (I think it's GNOME). Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Gnome nightlight, redshift or even Windows nightlight can do what you are asking but I wrote [eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) and it has been doing that for years:

[image: eyesome general.png]

[image: eyesome monitor 3.png]

I've been using it for years and look forward to enhancing it whenever a new problem or challenge comes along.